# Did Owen and Beru Lars ever meet R2-D2 during the events of prequels?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Did Owen and Beru Lars ever meet R2-D2 during the events of prequels?

I would be primarily interested in canon (3 prequel movies), but if there are no such instances in canon, an answer based on Legends is fine.

(I'm thinking of 2 possible instances: either when C-3PO was living with Shmi; or when R2-D2 accompanied Anakin to Tatooine when she was killed, would be my own 2 main possible guesses).

Comment: Strictly speaking, *during the events of prequels* only encompasses things depicted on-screen in the prequel trilogy. (At least, that's *my* interpretation.) So, the answer here would be "no". If you'd like something other than that, you'll have to open up the scope to include other canonical works that cover that period in Star Wars history.

Comment: @Iszi - Hmm... good point. I was only thinking 3 prequel movies, but now that you said it, if teh prequel answer is "no", it doesn't mean C-canon has no instances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

YES, R2-D2 accompanied Anakin to Tatooine and got out of the ship during Shmi's funeral:

[image: R2-D2, C-3PO, Padme and Anakin on Tatooine]

From the [*Attack of the Clones* script](https://web.archive.org/web/20111217191338/http://www.blueharvest.net/scoops/aotc-script.shtml)

> EXTERIOR: TATOOINE, HOMESTEAD, GRAVESITE - DAY
>
> ANAKIN, PADMÉ, CLIEGG, **OWEN, BERU**, and THREEPIO are
>   standing around Shmi's grave. Two other headstones, one
>   smaller than the other, stand in the blazing suns.
>
> CLIEGG: I know wherever you are it's become a better place.
>   You were the most loving partner a man could ever have.
>   Goodbye, my dearest wife. And thank you.
>
> Brief pause. ANAKIN steps forward and kneels at his
>   mother's grave. He picks up a handful of sand.
>
> ANAKIN: I wasn't strong enough to save you, Mom. I wasn't
>   strong enough. But I promise I won't fail again... (he
>   stands up) I miss you so much.
>
> Silence. **Then BEEPS and WHISTLES are heard. They turn as
>   ARTOO rolls up.**
>
> PADMÉ: Artoo, what are you doing here?
>
> ARTOO BEEPS and WHISTLES.
>
> C-3PO: It seems that he is carrying a message from an Obi-Wan Kenobi. Master Annie, does that name mean anything to
>   you?

Comment: Oh, wow.  Totally forgot about that.